# Angular 12 IVY angular-universal AppServerModuleNgFactory not exist

Tags: angular, angular12, ivy

necesito ayuda para pasar de Angular 11 SSR con view Engine a Angular 12 SSR con Ivy

Situación: Angular 12 + Universal SSR
He actualizado desde Angular 11 View Engine a Angular 12 Ivy en el SSR

Problemas: Tenemos un servidor PM2 con el SSR que ejecuta la web que le indiquemos, lo tenemos en un proyecto separado.

Recibimos el siguiente mensaje si uso en el SSR AppServerModuleNgFactory

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined

En el main.js creado con Angular 11 view Engine existe en su contenido AppServerModuleNgFactory pero en el main.js generado por Angular 12 Ivy no contiene el AppServerModuleNgFactory

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require(Path.resolve(
  process.cwd(),
  "lib/sites-ssr/main"
));
const fileLocation = Path.resolve(process.cwd(), "views") + "/index" + req.query.hashfile + ".html";
const indexHtml = readFileSync(fileLocation, "utf-8").toString();
const url = SITE_CONFIG.public_path + req.originalUrl.split("?")[0]";
renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
            document: indexHtml,
            url: url,
          })
          .then((html) => {
             res.status(200).send(new SSRResponse({
                posts: global["posts_ssr"],
             },html));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              res.sendStatus(500);
          });
```

Pero si en vez de AppServerModuleNgFactory uso AppServerModule el mensaje cambia

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

En la consola printo el objeto AppServerModule

> <ref *1> [class AppServerModule] {
> 'ɵfac': [Function: AppServerModule_Factory],
> 'ɵmod': {
> type: [Circular *1],
> bootstrap: [ [Function] ],
> declarations: [],
> imports: [],
> exports: [],
> transitiveCompileScopes: null,
> schemas: null,
> id: null    },    'ɵinj': { providers: [], imports: [ [Array] ] } }

Esta es la estructura del proyecto principal
-Project
-tsconfig.json
-package.json
-angular.json
-src
-app
-app.server.module.ts
-projects
-projectName
-main.server.ts
-tsconfig.app.json
-tsconfig.server.json
-src
-main.ts

Archivos:
package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng run projectName:build:production --optimization=true",
    "build-server": "ng run projectName:server:production"
}
```

angular.json

```
"projectName": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/projectName",
            "index": "projects/projectName/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/projectName/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/projectName/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/projectName/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/projectName/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/projectName/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "aot": true,
              "serviceWorker": false,
            },
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "nameProject:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "nameProject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/nameProject/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/nameProject/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/nameProject/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "./projects/nameProject/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "./projects/nameProject/tsconfig.server.json",
            "bundleDependencies": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true,
            },
          }
        },
      }
    }
```

build main.ts

```
import "zone.js";

enableProdMode();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(ProjectNameModule)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

build tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": false,
    "genDir": "compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "files": ["./src/main.ts", "./src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

build ../../tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "files": [
    "./projects/nameProject/src/main.ts",
    "./projects/nameProject/main.server.ts",
    "./src/polyfills.ts",
    "./custom.d.ts",
    "./src/app/app.module.ts",
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

server main.server.ts

```
import "zone.js";

enableProdMode();
export { AppServerModule } from "../../src/app/app.server.module";
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from "@angular/platform-server";
```

AppServerModule

```
import {
  ServerModule,
  ServerTransferStateModule,
} from "@angular/platform-server";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { NameProjectModule } from "../../projects/nameProject/src/app/nameProject.module";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [NameProjectModule, ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

server tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    // Set the module format to "commonjs":
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  // Add "angularCompilerOptions" with the AppServerModule you wrote
  // set as the "entryModule".
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule",
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

Estructura del proyecto SSR **y su orden de ejecución es app.ts -> view-render.controller.ts -> server.ts -> env-selector.ts**
-Project
-lib
-app.ts
-server.ts
-controllers
-view-renderer
-view-renderer.controller.ts
-sites-ssr
-environments
-env-selector.ts
-main.js

app.ts

```
constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.routes.routes(this.app); // routes in view-render.controller.ts
    this.app.disable("view cache");
}
```

view-render.controller.ts

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require("../../sites-ssr/main");

public routes(app) {
    this.app = app;
    app.route("*").post((req, res) => {
      this.proxyRequest(req, res);
    });
}

proxyRequest(req, res) {
      setEnv(this.app, req, res)
        .then((env) => {
          const fileLocation =
            Path.resolve(process.cwd(), "views") +
            "/index" +
            req.query.hashfile +
            ".html";

          const indexHtml = readFileSync(fileLocation, "utf-8").toString();
          const url = SITE_CONFIG.public_path + req.originalUrl.split("?")[0];

          res.render(fileLocation, { req }, function (err, html) {
            renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
              document: html,
              url: url,
            })
              .then((html) => {
                  res.send(
                    new SSRResponse(
                      {
                        posts: global["posts_ssr"],
                      },
                      html
                    )
                  );
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
              });
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
}
```